# Blank iSCSI targets but targets still active

Tags: iscsi, wmi, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I have a Windows server 2012 R2 core server running Hyper-v with iSCSI attachments. Many months ago I configured the iSCSI connections and everything was working fine. I recently went to add an additional connection however when i opened the iSCSI initiator interface i noticed under the 'Targets' tab the 'Discovered Targets' section was completely empty. The 'Discovery' tab had a portal pointing to our san, both the 'Favourite Targets' and 'Volumes & Devices' tabs were also blank.

I attempted to use the quick connect to connect to our SAN to see if this might resolve the issue however i received the following in the progress report section:

'The GUID passed was not recognized as valid by a WMI data provider.'

All existing iSCSI disk attachments are still present and all VM's are working fine. I am at a loss as to where to go from here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have also noticed similar behavior under Windows Server 2012. This can be just a visual glitch.

Use "Get-IscsiSession" Powershell cmdlet to ensure that iSCSI Initiator is working properly. If there is the correct session list in Powershell output, then everything is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this too, must only be happening to people who's names start "Dav" ;-)

My situation was similar, I had VM's and databases hosted off an iSCSI array in our dev platform. Blank target list, and same GUID error message.

My plan was to shut down all of the VMs on that host and then start troubleshooting by restarting the iSCSI service, however as soon as I shut down all of the VMs, the initiator suddenly re-populated the list and I was able to connect new targets.  No idea what was happening here but my problems started immediately after a power failure causing the host to go down un-gracefully.

Might be worth a try if you can.